# How to select all DML statement done to a table

Tags: oracle

With this query, I can see which table where modified last hour.

```
 select * from ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS where timestamp> sysdate-1/24
```

Now I want to know what has been insert, updates, deletes in a table. And if possible with the user id.

How do I do that?

I've tried to use audit.

> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/svgaa?topic=c-enabling-auditing-oracle-resource

in sqlplus
SHOW PARAMETER AUDIT_TRAIL

> DB --OK

```
  AUDIT ALL BY SEV BY ACCESS
```

> audit succeeded

I've tried to see the content of all the audit table (SELECT view_name FROM dba_views WHERE view_name LIKE 'DBA%AUDIT%';)

for instance :

```
 select * from dba_audit_exists;
```

but they are empty

Comment: Enable auditing. That's what it is designed for.

Comment: If auditing is not enabled, assuming you're running in archivelog mode, you could theoretically use LogMiner to go through all the archived logs for the last hour to get that information.  It would be a giant pain to do so (depending on the activity level of your system) but it would be doable.  But the right answer is to have enabled auditing an hour ago and then query the audit log.